# batch 7zip delete command does not delete files

Tags: cmd, 7zip

I need to delete specific files from lots of zip files using 7zip. This is the command I run:

`for %A in (*.zip) do 7z d %A app_store*.* default_*.png -r`

But it creates a blank *7z* file and does not delete the files from the zip. What is going wrong?

Comment: You should add the solution found as an answer and set it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was confused for last few days and solved it after posting it here.

The issue was spaces in the file names. When I added " to the second %A it worked:

`for %A in (*.zip) do 7z d "%A" app_store*.* default_*.png -r`

But still that was a hair pulling behaviour.